# Why variable replacement does not work in Python nested loop

Tags: python, loops

I have the following code:

```
lower_threshold = 6.33
upper_threshold = 1e+30
threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit = {
    "k2-01-003|15" : [15.007, 1e+30]
}
mylist = ['k2-01-003|18', 'k2-01-003|13','k2-01-003|15']

for i in range(3):
    for patient_visit in mylist:
        if (patient_visit in threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit):
            lower_threshold, upper_threshold = threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit[patient_visit]
        print(i, patient_visit, lower_threshold, upper_threshold)
```

The task I want to achieve is this:

1. Within the `range(3)` loop, loop through `mylist`.
2. When the content of my list exist in `threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit` dictionary (in this case `k2-01-003|15`)
   replace the `lower_threshold` and `upper_threshold` with the value in that dictionary.
   Otherwise use default value: `6.33` and `1e+30`

The result I expect is this:

```
0 k2-01-003|18 6.33 1e+30
0 k2-01-003|13 6.33 1e+30
0 k2-01-003|15 15.007 1e+30
1 k2-01-003|18 6.33 1e+30
1 k2-01-003|13 6.33 1e+30
1 k2-01-003|15 15.007 1e+30
2 k2-01-003|18 6.33 1e+30
2 k2-01-003|13 6.33 1e+30
2 k2-01-003|15 15.007 1e+30
```

Why it gives this instead:

```
0 k2-01-003|18 6.33 1e+30
0 k2-01-003|13 6.33 1e+30
0 k2-01-003|15 15.007 1e+30
1 k2-01-003|18 15.007 1e+30
1 k2-01-003|13 15.007 1e+30
1 k2-01-003|15 15.007 1e+30
2 k2-01-003|18 15.007 1e+30
2 k2-01-003|13 15.007 1e+30
2 k2-01-003|15 15.007 1e+30
```

What's the right way to go about it?

I'm using Python 3.8.5.

---

***Update***

I tried to add `else` but still doesn't work:

```
for i in range(3):
    for patient_visit in mylist:
        if (patient_visit in threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit):
            lower_threshold, upper_threshold = threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit[patient_visit]
        else:
            lower_threshold, upper_threshold = lower_threshold, upper_threshold
        print(i, patient_visit, lower_threshold, upper_threshold)
```

Comment: Add an `else` where you reset to the default values for the threshold variables?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried. It doesn't work. see my update above.

Comment: With `lower_threshold, upper_threshold = lower_threshold, upper_threshold` you just assign the same values as the variables already have. You need to assign the *default* value, explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```
threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit = {
    "k2-01-003|15" : (15.007, 1e+30) # using tuple instead of list because you don't need to mutate them; this is not mandatory
}
default_thresholds = (6.33, 1e+30)
mylist = ['k2-01-003|18', 'k2-01-003|13','k2-01-003|15']

for i in range(3):
    for patient_visit in mylist:
        #dict.get: get an item if it exists, otherwise return a default value
        lower_threshold, upper_threshold = threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit.get(patient_visit, default_thresholds)
        print(i, patient_visit, lower_threshold, upper_threshold)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean and working solution:

```
threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit = {
    "k2-01-003|15" : [15.007, 1e+30]
}
mylist = ['k2-01-003|18', 'k2-01-003|13','k2-01-003|15']

for i in range(3):
    lower_threshold = 6.33
    upper_threshold = 1e+30
    
    for patient_visit in mylist:
        if patient_visit in list(threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit.keys()):
            lower_threshold, upper_threshold = threshold_dict_by_patient_and_visit[patient_visit]
        print(i, patient_visit, lower_threshold, upper_threshold)
```